# 3 Pane Layout using SlidingPaneLayout like Yatra.com

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu, android-sliding, slidingpanelayout

I want a three column pane layout like [Yatra.com app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yatra.base) in which the sliding pane can slide from either left or right side. But SlidingPaneLayout only accepts two panes. When I try to put three fragments in there it doesn't show anything at all.

I tried changing the Sliding Pane Fragment with another view, but the solution is hacky and it doesn't slide from right at all. I got successful in having three panes using NavigationDrawer, but I don't want the pane to overlay the Main Fragment.

My question is, is it possible to have three panes using SLidingPaneLayout or should I try something else. If it's possible how can it be achieved? Am I missing something?

[image: Left Pane]
[image: Right Pane]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) it has a demo on [play store](http://bit.ly/TWejze)

Download all the libraries required by sliding drawer lib, download sample and see the **[Left and Right 
Activity](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/LeftAndRightActivity.java)** it is similar to what you wanted...

The main code to set left and right drawer is this line:

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
```

And then populate the right fragment like this:

```
 getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a savior. Although it still took me 4 hours to integrate, according to my need.